# Java 8 LocalDate from long to date not converted correct

Tags: java, date, localdate, zoneddatetime

I want to convert date in milliseconds to date but it doesn't convert correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    LocalDate today = LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate();
    System.out.println("Today: ----------" + today);
    long todayLong = today.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond();
    System.out.println("todayLong: ---------- " + todayLong);
    LocalDate todayBack = Instant.ofEpochMilli(todayLong).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    System.out.println("todayBack: ---------- "+todayBack);
}
```

Here is the output:

> Today: ----------2017-06-27
>
> todayLong: ---------- 1498507200
>
> todayBack: ---------- 1970-01-18

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need use `ofEpochSecond` instead of `ofEpochMilli` because your `todayLong` is `second`, not `milisecond`

```
LocalDate todayBack = Instant.ofEpochSecond(todayLong).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a little mistake at the 6th line (`Instant.ofEpochMilli`).
Use `Instant.ofEpochSecond` instead:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDateTime.now().toLocalDate();
System.out.println("Today: ----------" + today);
long todayLong = today.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond();
System.out.println("todayLong: ---------- " + todayLong);
LocalDate todayBack = Instant.ofEpochSecond(todayLong).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
System.out.println("todayBack: ---------- " + todayBack);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do multiply the todayLong by 1000

```
LocalDate todayBack = Instant.ofEpochMilli(todayLong * 1000).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

System.out.println("todayBack: ---------- " + todayBack);
```

to get the output:

> Today: ----------2017-06-27
>
> todayLong: ---------- 1498514400
>
> todayBack: ---------- 2017-06-27